# Having trouble trying to switch from MAMP to Laravel Vallet and using the Laravel command line tool

Tags: macos, laravel, terminal, mamp

I'm having problems trying to use the Laravel command installer with Mac 10.10.5 Yosemite.

From my understanding I have too:

> Make sure to place the $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin directory (or the equivalent directory for your OS) in your $PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system.

So I tried exporting the $PATH in two different ways:

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
```

I installed the laravel installer and I do see that the directory exists for the Laravel installer:

```
 ~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel/installer/...
```

The problem is when ever I use the laravel command I get:

```
-bash: laravel: command not found
```

I **echo $PATH** and I get this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I think there is something wrong with how the $PATH is set still. If I'm right how do I change this? If I'm wrong what do you think is going on?

I'm not going to try and install Vallet till I figure this out as I have a hunch that it won't work properly due to the same issue.

Comment: The exporting of this path is only reliable for 1 terminal session. Additional terminal sessions won't know about that variable. you need to add it to your ~/.bashrc file so that all terminal sessions can know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will indeed need to add the composer path to your `$PATH`,

Which can be done by adding:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

To your `~/.bash_profile`

This will add the path to your `$PATH` every time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm not the most experienced with terminal stuff. I'm just going to check before doing this, would I just add that to my ~/.bash_profile by doing this:

     export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"  >>~/.bash_profile


Or is there another way?

Comment: Either would work, that "string" just needs to be on a separate line in that file. There is no difference in how it gets there.

Comment: Okay I just open the .bash_profile in nano and I see:

export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin:$PATH

Do I leave that and add your code, or do I change that to your code?

Comment: You add the string I posted (on a new line) in the file